# Can't update query inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a program where in you'll set a daily target and divide it to 6 due to it will update every 4hours and add the value that has been divided every 4 hours. But when I tried to put the query result inside the loop, it isn't working well. When I tried to put it inside the array and create a loop for it then update but the program process is slow. Any help that'll make my program to work. thanks

```
<?php

                    if(isset($_POST['clicked'])){

                    $mysqli = new mysqli('10.237.2.152','root','c0k3float','monitoring');

                    $datess = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                     // echo "<script> alert('".$datess."'); </script>";
                    $timeplan = $_POST['submitTime'];

                    $a = array();

                    $results=$mysqli->query("SELECT * from Shipment_Target") or mysqli0;

                    while($row = $results->fetch_array())  {
                        $temp = $row['twohrs_target'];
                        $id = $row['id'];   
                        if ($timeplan =='6:00 AM-10:00 AM'){
                            $temp*=1;

                             $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Shipment_Target SET target=".$temp." where id=".$id." ");
                        }
                        else if ($timeplan == '6:00 AM-10:00 AM'){
                            $temp*=2;

                        }
                        else if ($timeplan == '10:00 AM-2:00 PM'){
                            $temp*=3;

                        }

                        else if ($timeplan =='2:00 PM-6:00 PM'){
                            $temp*=4;
                            //array_push($a,$temp);
                        }





                    }
                    // for($x=0; $X<=count($a); $x++){


                    // }
                    echo "<script> alert(".$res = count($a).");</script>";

                    echo "<script> window.location='shipment.php' </script>";

                    // $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Shipment_Target SET time='".$_POST['submitTime']."',target=".$temp.", date='".$datess."' ") or mysqli0;





                    }

                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override your `$result` variable inside the look.

```
// Here $result is the query SELECT
$results=$mysqli->query("SELECT * from Shipment_Target") or mysqli0;
while($row = $results->fetch_array())  {
    $temp = $row['twohrs_target'];
    $id = $row['id'];   
    if ($timeplan =='6:00 AM-10:00 AM'){
        $temp*=1;

        // Here $result is the query UPDATE
         $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Shipment_Target SET target=".$temp." where id=".$id." ");
    }
```

You can use a different variable name, but don't use the same variable.

Comment: ohh i see, Let me try and ill get back to you sir.

Comment: oh wait. it isn't still updating i was very excited due to the alert script came to true until the end of the loop but it isn't updating the column i wanted to update :(

Comment: maybe your query is wrong. But this will solve your problem :)

Comment: i found that i haven't put any value on other column hehe. problem solved. Thank you again!

Comment: I think you might want to move the UPDATE query to be **after** all of the `if..else if`block.

Comment: yes i will do that. i just tried it to put inside the if else block if it is working inside of it. Thank you